# QRegularExpression to find numeric part of file name

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregularexpression

I have the entire path of a file available in a Qstring

```
Qstring str = "d://output/File_012_xyz/logs";
```

From this I wanted to extract the number 12.

I tried something like this

```
QRegularExpression rx("[1-9]+");

QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = rx.globalMatch(str );
if (i.hasNext())
{
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    QString word = match.captured(1);
    quint32 myNum = word.toUInt();
}
```

This always returns myNum as 0. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked to return a capturing group #1 value with [`.captured(1)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatch.html#captured), but your regex has no capturing groups defined in it.

You may use

```
QRegularExpression rx("[1-9][0-9]*");

QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = rx.globalMatch(str );
if (i.hasNext())
{
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    QString word = match.captured(0);         // <<< SEE HERE
    quint32 myNum = word.toUInt();
}
```

The `0`th group is the whole match.

Also, the pattern like `[1-9]+` won't match `10` or `200`, thus, I suggest using `[1-9][0-9]*`: a non-0 digit followed with 0 or more digits.